# multithreading - threads per core

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, performance

I have this code:

```
#define threadsNum 4

DWORD WINAPI func(LPVOID vpParam)
{
    long long sum = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 400000 / threadsNum; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 160000 / threadsNum; j++)
        {
            sum = sum > 1000 ? 0 : sum + 1;
        }

    }

    return 1;
}


int main()
{
    clock_t timer = clock();

    int CPUs = 4;
    DWORD_PTR threadCore = 1;
    DWORD_PTR threadID = 0;
    int addNum = 0;

    void* *threads = new void*[threadsNum];

    for (int i = 0; i < threadsNum; i++)
    {
        threadCore = 1 << addNum;
        addNum++;
        if (addNum == 4)
            addNum = 0;

        threads[i] = CreateThread(0, 0, func, NULL , 0, &threadID);
        SetThreadAffinityMask(threads[i], threadCore);
    }

    if (WaitForMultipleObjects(threadsNum, threads, true, INFINITE) == WAIT_FAILED)
        FatalAppExitA(NULL, "FAIL");


    cout<<clock() - timer<<endl;

    getchar();


    return 1;
}
```

I have 4 cores on my pc. as the number of `threadsNum` goes up the time is smaller. When `threadsNum` equals to 4, the output is 22325 and when it is 8 the output is 11549. Why? every core do the same work. for `threadsNum = 8` every core has 2 threads which together do the same job when `threadsNum = 4`. So why it is faster?

Comment: Threads may be preemted and might be doing some IO...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If 8 threads are that much faster than 4 on a 4-core CPU, you probably have one of the Intel CPUs with Hyperthreading, which runs two hardware threads per core. It's not usually as fast as an actual 8-core CPU would be because the two threads on each core are sharing some hardware resources, but for a simple thread payload like this you might get close to a factor of 2 improvement (and seem to be doing so).

Comment: op could try plotting execution time from thread numbers going from 1 to 64 - that would expose thread patterns from the cpu. Modern cpu have loop reorganization and branch prediction anyway, which both help and hide performances on these kind of synthetic benchmarks.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 primary culprits but you will have to benchmark more to find out how much each is contributing.

1. IO-bound tasks where threads are blocked by IO. In this case, the "IO" would be memory accesses. One thread can do addition while another is blocked waiting for a read or write.
2. [Hyperthreading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading). In modern processors, each core can almost behave like two cores.